# Function with domain from data table

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I have a `Table` with elements `{{i1, j1, k1},{i2, j2, k2},...}`

I wanted to store the values of `{{a1, b1, c1},{a2, b2, c2},...}` in a table where

```
a = f(i, j, k)
b = g(i, j, k)
c = h(i, j, k)
```

are simple functions of `i`, `j`, and `k`.

This seems to be quite a simple task but I can't seem to access the values properly, and am not familiar with `Thread`, `Transpose`, `Interpolation`, etc, so any suggestions on how to efficiently do the task would be very helpful.

Comment: `Through /@ {f, g, h} /@ {{i1, j1, k1}, {i2, j2, k2}}` ?

Comment: ... or `Through[{f,g,h}@##]&@@@{{i1, j1, k1}, {i2, j2, k2}}` or `Through[{f, g, h} @@ #] & /@ {{i1, j1, k1}, {i2, j2, k2}}`

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It is not quite correct.

Comment: @kglr - In general how do I call all the Table elements {{i_n,  j_n,  k_n}...}? And could you elaborate a little on what exactly your syntax does?

Comment: Sarah, `Through[{f,g,h}@##]&@@@yourTable`  should transform each triple `{i,j,k}` to `{f[i,j,k],g[i,j,k],h[i,j,k]}`. How it works: (1) `Through[{f, g, h}@arg]` gives `{f[arg],g[arg],h[arg]`. (2)  The form `@@@` is short for `Apply at level 1` (see [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html)). So, `foo@@@{{a,b,c},{u,s,t},{v,w,z}}` gives `{foo[a,b,c],foo[u,s,t],foo[v,w,z]}`. ((In contrast, `Map`ing `foo` on the same list, `foo/@{{a,b,c},{u,s,t},{v,w,z}}` gives `{foo[{a,b,c}], foo[{u,s,t}],foo[{v,w,z}]}`).

Comment: Sarah, I would suggest that you remove the second part of your question ("Additionally, it would...") from this post, as it seems quite independent of the first part, and post it as a separate question.

Comment: @MarcoB - I have done that, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @kglr - That is very helpful, thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by generating a small sample from a table like yours, for demonstration:

```
table = Array[Through[{i, j, k}[#]] &, 2]

(* Out:
{{i[1], j[1], k[1]}, {i[2], j[2], k[2]}}
*)
```

---

In my view, perhaps the most immediately readable approach to your problem might be the following:

```
{f[##], g[##], h[##]}& @@@ table

(* Out:
{{f[i[1], j[1], k[1]], g[i[1], j[1], k[1]], h[i[1], j[1], k[1]]},
 {f[i[2], j[2], k[2]], g[i[2], j[2], k[2]], h[i[2], j[2], k[2]]}}
*)
```

You will want to take a look at [the docs for `Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) if this syntax or the equivalent `Apply[function, input, {1}]` are unfamiliar to you.

---

A more compact way to generate that functional expression is the following, as [suggested by @kglr in comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174091/function-with-domain-from-data-table#comment456997_174091):

```
Through[{f, g, h}[##]]& @@@ table
```

You can convince yourself that the `Through` expression essentially generates a functional form equivalent to the one I first proposed above as follows:

```
Evaluate[ Through[{f, g, h}[##]] ] &

(* Out: {f[##1], g[##1], h[##1]} & *)
```

where `##1` is equivalent to `##` (see [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html)).

Answer (score 4):

```
table = {{i[1], j[1], k[1]}, {i[2], j[2], k[2]}};
```

Using `ComapApply` (new in 14.0)

```
ComapApply[{f, g, h}] /@ table
```

returns

```
{{f[i[1], j[1], k[1]], g[i[1], j[1], k[1]], h[i[1], j[1], k[1]]}, 
 {f[i[2], j[2], k[2]], g[i[2], j[2], k[2]], h[i[2], j[2], k[2]]}}
```

Compare to `Query`

```
Query[All, Apply /@ {f, g, h}] @ table
```

(* same result *)

Answer (score 2):

Since I use an older version (v12.2.0), the `Co-Map-Apply` can be implemented using:

```
list = {{i1, j1, k1}, {i2, j2, k2}, {i3, j3, k3}}

Transpose@Outer[Compose, Map[Apply][{f, g, h}], list, 1]
```

> {{f[i1, j1, k1], g[i1, j1, k1], h[i1, j1, k1]}, {f[i2, j2, k2],
> g[i2, j2, k2], h[i2, j2, k2]}, {f[i3, j3, k3], g[i3, j3, k3],    h[i3,
> j3, k3]}}

Answer (score 2):

```
table = {{i[1], j[1], k[1]}, {i[2], j[2], k[2]}};
```

Another way using `BlockMap`:

```
Transpose@BlockMap[Sequence @@ {f @@@ #, g @@@ #, h @@@ #} &, table, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{f[i[1], j[1], k[1]], g[i[1], j[1], k[1]], h[i[1], j[1], k[1]]}, 
>  {f[i[2], j[2], k[2]], g[i[2], j[2], k[2]], h[i[2], j[2], k[2]]}}
> ```

Or using `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[{f @@ #, g @@ #, h @@ #} &, table[[#]], All] & /@ Range@Length@table
```

> ```
> {{f[i[1], j[1], k[1]], g[i[1], j[1], k[1]], h[i[1], j[1], k[1]]}, 
>  {f[i[2], j[2], k[2]], g[i[2], j[2], k[2]], h[i[2], j[2], k[2]]}}
> ```